# Changing background image like slider

Tags: javascript

Please help me, i am new in JS.So, as you can see i have 12 divs with some backgorund images.I want to change these 12 backgorund images at the same tame when prev. or next are clicked. But i do not know how to do that.I have some JS code,it works, when i simply change image src. Now  how can i change it for changing background-images?Thanks in advance.

```
               <a href="#"><div onClick="show2(this.style)"class="img" style="background-image:url('css/images1/img/img1.jpg');background-size:90% 90%;")></div></a>
                <a href="#"><div onClick="show2(this.style)"class="img" style="background-image:url('css/images1/img/img2.jpg');background-size:90% 90%;")></div></a>
                <a href="#"><div onClick="show2(this.style)"class="img" style="background-image:url('css/images1/img/img3.jpg');background-size:90% 90%;")></div></a>
                <a href="#"><div onClick="show2(this.src)"class="img" style="background-image:url('css/images1/img/img4.jpg');background-size:90% 90%;")></div></a>
                <a href="#"><div onClick="show2(this.src)"class="img" style="background-image:url('css/images1/img/img5.jpg');background-size:90% 90%;")></div></a>
                <a href="#"><div onClick="show2(this.src)"class="img" style="background-image:url('css/images1/img/img6.jpg');background-size:90% 90%;")></div></a>
                <a href="#"><div onClick="show2(this.src)"class="img" style="background-image:url('css/images1/img/img7.jpg');background-size:90% 90%;")></div></a>
                <a href="#"><div onClick="show2(this.src)"class="img" style="background-image:url('css/images1/img/img8.jpg');background-size:90% 90%;")></div></a>
                <a href="#"><div onClick="show2(this.src)"class="img" style="background-image:url('css/images1/img/img9.jpg');background-size:90% 90%;")></div></a>
                <a href="#"><div onClick="show2(this.src)"class="img" style="background-image:url('css/images1/img/img10.jpg');background-size:90% 90%;")></div></a>
                <a href="#"><div onClick="show2(this.src)"class="img" style="background-image:url('css/images1/img/img11.jpg');background-size:90% 90%;")></div></a>
                <a href="#"><div onClick="show2(this.src)"class="img" style="background-image:url('css/images1/img/img12.jpg');background-size:90% 90%;")></div></a>


                 <div class="arrowswrapper"><a href="#" onClick="next(-1)" style="float:left">prev.</a><a href="#" onClick="next(1)" style="float:right">next</a> </div>

var step = 12;
var total = 100;
function next(x) {
    var image = document.getElementsByClassName("img");
    for (var i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
        step = step + x;
        if (step > total) {
            step = 12;
        }
        if (step < 12) {
            step = total;
        }
        image[i].src = "css/images1/img/img" + step + ".png";

    };
};
```

Comment: Please fix validation and indent of your code. Also it will be helpful if full jsfiddle with js, html and css will be added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `image[i].src = "css/images1/img/img" + step + ".png";` by `image[i].style.backgroundImage= "url('css/images1/img/img" + step + ".png')";`. It should do the trick.

You can get more info [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundimage.asp).